# Como seleccionar registros sin duplicar pero sumando la cantidad?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, xampp

Tengo una duda, es posible hacer lo siguiente?

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT d.cod_producto, p.descripcion, p.precio_costo, p.precio_venta, d.cantidad from detalle_factura d
inner join producto p
on p.id_producto = d.cod_producto
inner join factura f
on f.id_factura = d.cod_factura
where
(fecha_facturacion BETWEEN '2022-05-06' AND '2022-05-09')
```

Esa consulta me trae los siguiente registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que esa consulta me de la suma de la cantidad donde los registros tienen el mismo cod_producto y que me muestre un solo registro por cod_producto, exactamente asi:

| cod_producto | descripcion | precio_costo | precio_venta | cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Llave 1000 | 700 | 2500 | 14 |
| 2 | Chapa | 12000 | 20000 | 1 |
| 3 | Llaveros | 3000 | 6000 | 3 |
| 6 | Candado | 8000 | 14000 | 2 |

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que la información de tus tablas es solo la que muestras en el query, hice la tarea de crear las tablas en SQL fiddle para poder probar...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `producto` (
  `id_producto` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `precio_costo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `precio_venta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_producto`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `producto` (`id_producto`, `descripcion`, `precio_costo`, `precio_venta`) VALUES
  (1, 'Lave 1000', 700, 2500),
  (2, 'Chapa', 12000, 20000),
  (3, 'Llaveros', 3000, 6000),
  (6, 'Candado', 8000, 14000);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detalle_factura` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cod_producto` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cod_factura` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `detalle_factura` (`id`, `cod_producto`, `cantidad`, `cod_factura`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 3, 1),
  (2, 2, 1, 1),
  (3, 3, 3, 1),
  (4, 1, 8, 2),
  (5, 6, 2, 2),
  (6, 1, 3, 3);
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `factura` (
  `id_factura` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fecha_facturacion` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_factura`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `factura` (`id_factura`, `fecha_facturacion`) VALUES
  (1, '2022-05-06'),
  (2, '2022-05-07'),
  (3, '2022-05-09');
```

Luego, el query que puedes usar para obtener los resultados como los presentas, es el siguiente:

```
SELECT d.cod_producto, p.descripcion, p.precio_costo, p.precio_venta, sum(d.cantidad) cantidad 
from detalle_factura d
inner join producto p on p.id_producto = d.cod_producto
inner join factura f on f.id_factura = d.cod_factura
where (fecha_facturacion BETWEEN '2022-05-06' AND '2022-05-09')
group by d.cod_producto;
```

Donde, sumas la cantidad de productos `sum(d.cantidad)` y los agrupas por el código del producto `group by d.cod_producto`, obteniendo la salida que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que capo, muchas gracias me funciono a la perfeccion, ya habia intentado hacerlo programando (sumar la cantidad donde se repitiera el codigo y remover los duplicados posteriormente) pero era muchisimo mas complejo asi.